# SymLink only works in the same directory

Tags: debian, symbolic-link

```
user@laptop ~ $ sudo ln -s ~/Games/JA/openjk.i386 ~/Desktop/JA
user@laptop ~ $ readlink -f ~/Desktop/JA
/home/user/Games/JA/openjk.i386
```

As you can see, the symlink points to the file, but when I try to click on it it doesn't work. However, if I put the JA symlink in the same directory as the file it is linking to (in this case `~/Games/JA`) it works. How do I make it work outside that directory (in the `Desktop`, for example)?

Comment: First of all, don't use `sudo` for this, that means the link will be owned by `root`, not your user and you don't need it anyway. Is this _exactly_ what you're doing? I just repeated it and it works as expected on my Debian. Do you have access to all directories in question? What happens when you click on the link? What _should_ happen? What kind of file is `openjk.i386`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem surely is, that the binary `openjk.i386` surely expecting some files in its directory. But the binary assumes, that its directory is `~/Desktop/`, where the required files are not found.

I would recommend using a very small script instead of a symbolic link. E.g. it should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /pathToBinary/
./binary $@
```

Name the file JA and make it executable with `chmod a+x JA`.

**Explanation:** The `$@` assures, that if your script is started with any arguments, they will be forwarded to the real binary.